# Allocating more CPU usage to MATLAB

Tags: macos, cpu-usage, matlab

I was wondering if there was a way to allocate more CPU usage to MATLAB. Currently, it says that 85% of my CPU is is idle. Is there some way to increase the threads MATLAB uses, or something along those lines?
For reference, my computer is a 2.7 GHz i7 8GB MacBook.

Comment: Would depend on what Matlab is doing.
If it is waiting for I/O (reading/writing a file) it will not consume as much CPU power as it would if it was calculating a lot of things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the OS exploit multiple cores](http://superuser.com/questions/531690/does-the-os-exploit-multiple-cores), it's a different wording but the answer is the same.

Comment: Would also depend on what version your using

Comment: I think probably the best you could do is invoke MATLab with the command line utility `nice` to give it the highest CPU scheduling priority.

Answer (score 0):

Though I could imagine that some tasks may already be allocated to multiple cores, the general way to enable parallel programming is by getting the 'parallel programming toolbox'.

This gives you the option to replace some of your `for` loops by `parfor` loops.

If you don't have this toolbox, you may want to look into a free alternative like:

[Run a script that uses multiple MATLAB sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204663/run-a-script-that-uses-multiple-matlab-sessions).

Of course this would require a stricter separation of the code, but it may not be too much work to achieve this.